# ComboBox SelectedValuePath SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I'm new to WPF and the concept of databinding, and I am in the process of teaching myself (with this application and a few books).

I've tried searching, but there are lots of questions (and answers) about how to bind it, but not how to reference/use the selected Item from the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath:

Overview:
I'm populating a ComboBox on window_loaded as below:

```
Private db As New Pluto_DBDataContext()
Private OrganisationTypeView As BindingListCollectionView

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    LoadOrganisationType()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadOrganisationType()
    Dim OrganisationTypeList = From EntOrgs In db.t_EntityOrgs
                               Join EntType In db.t_EntityTypes On EntType.ID Equals EntOrgs.FK_EntityType_ID
                               Order By EntOrgs.OrganisationType
                               Where EntOrgs.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntType.DateTime_To Is Nothing _
                               AndAlso ((Not bolIndividualEntityType) And EntType.EntityType <> "Individual")
                               Select EntOrgs.OrganisationType, EntOrgs.ID

    OrganisationType_ComboBox.DataContext = OrganisationTypeList
    Me.OrganisationTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OrganisationType_ComboBox.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="OrganisationType_ComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValue="{Binding OrganisationType}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="OrganisationType"/>
```

ComboBox_SelectionChanged:
I then use the selected OrganisationType to filter a ListView of clients as below (Note there are other controls that also trigger RefreshOrganisationClientList()).

This is where my problem lies. How do I get the selected value AND/OR the ID (SelectedValuePath) for that selection.

```
Private Sub OrganisationType_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectionChanged
    If OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        RefreshOrganisationClientList()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshOrganisationClientList()
    Dim sOrgType As String
    Dim guOrgType_ID As Guid
    Dim sOrganisationName As String
    Dim sPostCode As String
    Dim sOccupation As String

    If OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        sOrgType = Nothing
    Else
        '*****PROBLEM HERE*****
        sOrgType = OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem.index(1).ToString
        guOrgType_ID = OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem

        'guOrgType_ID = Guid.Parse(OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValuePath)

    End If
    MsgBox(sOrgType)
    MsgBox(guOrgType_ID)

    sOrganisationName = OrganisationName_TextBox.Text
    sPostCode = OrgPostalCode_TextBox.Text
    sOccupation = OrgOccupation_TextBox.Text

    Dim FilteredClientList = From Clients In db.t_Clients
                             Join EntType In db.t_EntityTypes On EntType.ID Equals Clients.FK_EntityType_ID
                             Join EntOrgs In db.t_EntityOrgs On EntType.ID Equals EntOrgs.FK_EntityType_ID
                             Order By Clients.OrganisationName, Clients.Occupation, EntOrgs.OrganisationType
                             Where Clients.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntType.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntOrgs.DateTime_To Is Nothing _
                             AndAlso ((Not bolIndividualEntityType) And EntType.EntityType <> "Individual") _
                             AndAlso (If(sOrgType IsNot Nothing, EntOrgs.ID = guOrgType_ID, True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sOrganisationName IsNot "", Clients.OrganisationName Like "*" & sOrganisationName & "*", True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sPostCode IsNot "", Clients.Postal_Code Like "*" & sPostCode & "*", True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sOccupation IsNot "", Clients.Occupation Like "*" & sOccupation & "*", True))
                             Select Clients.OrganisationName, EntOrgs.OrganisationType, Clients.Occupation, Clients.FormationDate, Clients.Postal_Code, Clients.ID

    ExistingOrganisationClients_ListView.DataContext = FilteredClientList
    Me.FilteredOrgansiationClientView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ExistingOrganisationClients_ListView.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```

I'm starting to think I'm misunderstanding the concept databinding itself and how to use the data selected from controls that are data bound, or I have overlooked something simple.

EDIT: I tried to post an image but since I'm new here, I'm unable to do so, so a description and an imgur link will have to do:
In both of the below "Partnerships" was selected from the ComboBox not "Charity". Charity is the first item in the list presented to the user.

Contents of SelectedValue:
[SelectedValue Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDm3P.jpg)

```
-    OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValue    "Charity"   Object {String}
```

Contents of SelectedItem:
[SelectedItem Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MusNL.jpg)

```
-    OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem OrganisationType="Partnerships", ID={27775e86-0013-4b82-996f-f6c061e99b2f}  Object {VB$AnonymousType_3(Of String, System.Guid)}
    +    ID {27775e86-0013-4b82-996f-f6c061e99b2f}  System.Guid
    -    OrganisationType   "Partnerships"  String
```

EDIT: For anyone that stumbles across this later on; the below is the updated to fix the above problem. Thanks again!:

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="OrganisationType_ComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="OrganisationType"/>
```

ComboBox_SelectionChanged:

```
Private Sub RefreshOrganisationClientList()
    Dim sOrgType As String
    Dim guOrgType_ID As Guid
    Dim sOrganisationName As String
    Dim sPostCode As String
    Dim sOccupation As String

    If OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        guOrgType_ID = Nothing
    Else
        guOrgType_ID = OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValue
    End If

    sOrganisationName = OrganisationName_TextBox.Text
    sPostCode = OrgPostalCode_TextBox.Text
    sOccupation = OrgOccupation_TextBox.Text

    Dim FilteredClientList = From Clients In db.t_Clients
                             Join EntType In db.t_EntityTypes On EntType.ID Equals Clients.FK_EntityType_ID
                             Join EntOrgs In db.t_EntityOrgs On EntType.ID Equals EntOrgs.FK_EntityType_ID
                             Order By Clients.OrganisationName, Clients.Occupation, EntOrgs.OrganisationType
                             Where Clients.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntType.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntOrgs.DateTime_To Is Nothing _
                             AndAlso ((Not bolIndividualEntityType) And EntType.EntityType <> "Individual") _
                             AndAlso (If(guOrgType_ID <> Guid.Empty, EntOrgs.ID = guOrgType_ID, True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sOrganisationName IsNot "", Clients.OrganisationName Like "*" & sOrganisationName & "*", True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sPostCode IsNot "", Clients.Postal_Code Like "*" & sPostCode & "*", True)) _
                             AndAlso (If(sOccupation IsNot "", Clients.Occupation Like "*" & sOccupation & "*", True))
                             Select Clients.OrganisationName, EntOrgs.OrganisationType, Clients.Occupation, Clients.FormationDate, Clients.Postal_Code, Clients.ID

    ExistingOrganisationClients_ListView.DataContext = FilteredClientList
    Me.FilteredOrgansiationClientView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ExistingOrganisationClients_ListView.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you populate your combobox with instances of an *anonymous type*:

```
Dim OrganisationTypeList = From EntOrgs In db.t_EntityOrgs
                           Join EntType In db.t_EntityTypes On EntType.ID Equals EntOrgs.FK_EntityType_ID
                           Order By EntOrgs.OrganisationType
                           Where EntOrgs.DateTime_To Is Nothing AndAlso EntType.DateTime_To Is Nothing _
                           AndAlso ((Not bolIndividualEntityType) And EntType.EntityType <> "Individual")
                           Select EntOrgs.OrganisationType, EntOrgs.ID

OrganisationType_ComboBox.DataContext = OrganisationTypeList
```

When the user selects something, `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will be an instance of that anonymous type. You'll need a couple lines of reflection code to get any property values out of it, because you can't cast it to anything.

Fortunately, you had the good sense to set `SelectedValuePath="ID"` on the combobox. If `SelectedValuePath` names a property that actually exists on the selected item, the `ComboBox` will do all that reflection work for you, get the value of that named property from the selected item, and stuff it in the `SelectedValue` property. In this case, that should be `SelectedItem.ID`.

```
Guid selectedID = (Guid)OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

I'm guessing here that `EntOrgs.ID` is of type `Guid`. If it isn't, substitute whatever type it actually is.

```
int selectedID = (int)OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Or whatever.

Comment: Yes the ID is a GUID. OrganisationType_ComboBox.SelectedValue returns the text description (OrganisationType) of the 1st item in the ComboBox not the selected item or the ID for that selected item.

Comment: Try removing `SelectedValue="{Binding OrganisationType}"` from the XAML, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Yep fantastic that worked! The example I was using has SelectedValue="{Binding *****}". Now I'm looking at it again, is that just saying that regardless of what's selected, return the entire bound list when asked what the SelectedValue is? If so I can't see why that would ever be used?

Comment: You would ordinarily bind SelectedValue to a property of the viewmodel (of type Guid in this case), and the viewmodel would ordinarily be the datacontext of the combobox. The items collection would be some property of the viewmodel. I guess maybe in "{Binding ****}", the asterisks might mean "whatever your property name is". Not how I'd express that concept!

Comment: @G.Williams There's some shockingly awful "information" out there.